# Struggling with grouped bar chart (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where each row indicates a patient that was screened by one of our research assistants. One column indicates the name of the study, and another column indicates what research assistant screened the patient:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G35cI.png)

| Study | RA1 |
| --- | --- |
| EMM | GL |
| EMM | GL |
| BIPAP | GL |
| BIPAP | HH |
| BIPAP | AS |

I want to generate something similar to this:

[image]

Where "Study" would be in the X axis, Number of patients screened on the Y axis, and each color would represent each of the research assistants.

I am not sure how to present the "sum" of screened patients by each research assistant to ggplot for the Y axis. Do I need to create a new variable for the y argument? If so, how would I create that variable?

```r
ggplot(data, aes(fill=RA1, y=**???**, x=Study)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Comment: `geom_bar` by default counts the number of cases; adding `stat="identity"` changes this behavior to be like `geom_col`, where you must provide the y value.

Comment: I suggest looking around at https://r-graph-gallery.com/, it's a "picture menu" of sorts with plots of plots, and the code and data to reproduce them. It's a great place to shop around for a plot that looks appropriate for what you need.

Comment: @Jon Spring YES! You are totally right. I deleted stat identity and didn't provide the Y value and it calculated the count for me. THANKS!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the suggestion! This is where I got the example from, but it had the stat set as "Identity" which was throwing me off.